# MMO WebSocket Server: Node.js or C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, performance, server

I have been thinking of making a real-time game with WebSockets for the web. I know how to use Node.js, and it is tempting to make it on there. But everywhere I look, C++ seems to be the popular server language because of its speed.

Should I give making it in Node.js a go, and worry about C++ later, or should I learn C++ now and make it in there from scratch?

Comment: Unless you're doing CPU-bound work, Node.js is probably fine.

Comment: @SLaks, say I was making Agar.io, which would be better?

Answer (score 11):

If you do decide to go the C++ route (and that does offer the best performance of any language), there's this great open source Websocket library that does all the heavy lifting for you. Its header-only and uses just boost. It comes with example code and documentation:
http://vinniefalco.github.io/

Here's a complete program that sends a message to the echo server:

```
#include <beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <beast/buffers_debug.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Normal boost::asio setup
    std::string const host = "echo.websocket.org";
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver r(ios);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(ios);
    boost::asio::connect(sock,
        r.resolve(boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query{host, "80"}));

    using namespace beast::websocket;

    // WebSocket connect and send message using beast
    stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket&> ws(sock);
    ws.handshake(host, "/");
    ws.write(boost::asio::buffer("Hello, world!"));

    // Receive WebSocket message, print and close using beast
    beast::streambuf sb;
    opcode op;
    ws.read(op, sb);
    ws.close(close_code::normal);
    std::cout <<
        beast::debug::buffers_to_string(sb.data()) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to use your library to make a WebSocket server? Is there any example code available for this?

Comment: There is TONS of example code! https://github.com/vinniefalco/Beast/tree/master/example Check out 'server-framework' it has WebSocket servers (SSL and non SSL, as well as ports handling both HTTP and WebSocket)

Answer (score 5):

Google's V8 engine used for Node.js does a great job compiling effective machine code. Javascript gets good enough performance to be used in games, aside from [special attention required on memory/garbage collection.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Op52liUjvSk), and [this lead to a lot of native C++ PC games being converted into browser javascript games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js). (notably, humble bundle ran a "Mozilla Bundle" which had a lot of these converted JS games, including "AaaaaAAaaaAAAaaAAAAaAAAAA!!! ", "FTL", etc.)

A lot of real-time games servers are created with Node.js along with [socket.io.](http://socket.io/) It is easy to get a basic websocket server running with node and socket.io, so you should be able to quickly build a prototype server, and do some performance testing to see if it will be sufficient for your application.

Comment: Socket.io is slow -1 for socket.io. uWS greatly outperforms socket.io +1 for nodejs and +1 for js. Result: +1